# upgrade turtlebot diamondback to electric

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I want to upgrade turtlebot from diamondback to electric, but when I follow the instructions from [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot/electric/Robot%20Upgrade) i get this on the terminal:

Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-electric-turtlebot-robot

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11725/upgrade-turtlebot-diamondback-to-electric/) by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 318 on 2011-10-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on 2011-10-31**:
I've Ubuntu 11.04 installed on my computer

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-10-31**:
What linux distro are you running?

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-10-28**:
That's odd try doing a sudo apt-get update again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

11.04 electric debs are up to date and available.  Can you make sure to update and try again?  Can you confirm that you have the ROS sources in your apt sources?  If you're still having trouble please provide more information.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0